# Python IPv6 Multicast Error on MAC OSX

Tags: python, macos, sockets, ipv6, multicast

I am trying to work with multicast in python using the example script below which is also available at 
[this location](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/sockets/mcast.py).

```
MYPORT = 8123
MYGROUP_4 = '225.0.0.250'
MYGROUP_6 = 'ff15:7079:7468:6f6e:6465:6d6f:6d63:6173'
MYTTL = 1 # Increase to reach other networks

import time
import struct
import socket
import sys

def main():
    group = MYGROUP_6 if "-6" in sys.argv[1:] else MYGROUP_4

    if "-s" in sys.argv[1:]:
        sender(group)
    else:
        receiver(group)


def sender(group):
    addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(group, None)[0]

    s = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    # Set Time-to-live (optional)
    ttl_bin = struct.pack('@i', MYTTL)
    if addrinfo[0] == socket.AF_INET: # IPv4
        s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl_bin)
    else:
        s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS, ttl_bin)

    while True:
        data = repr(time.time())
        s.sendto(data + '\0', (addrinfo[4][0], MYPORT))
        time.sleep(1)


def receiver(group):
    # Look up multicast group address in name server and find out IP version
    addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(group, None)[0]

    # Create a socket
    s = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    # Allow multiple copies of this program on one machine
    # (not strictly needed)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    # Bind it to the port
    s.bind(('', MYPORT))

    group_bin = socket.inet_pton(addrinfo[0], addrinfo[4][0])
    # Join group
    if addrinfo[0] == socket.AF_INET: # IPv4
        mreq = group_bin + struct.pack('=I', socket.INADDR_ANY)
        s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
    else:
        mreq = group_bin + struct.pack('@I', 0)
        s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, mreq)

    # Loop, printing any data we receive
    while True:
        data, sender = s.recvfrom(1500)
        while data[-1:] == '\0': data = data[:-1] # Strip trailing \0's
        print (str(sender) + '  ' + repr(data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The script however does not function when run on MAC OSX 10.8 using python 2.7 as expected and throws the following error:

```
[Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
```

Anyone got any idea what the problem is? I have tried to run it on an Ubuntu 13.04 virtual machine and it works just fine so it seems the problem is with MAC OSX

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following:

```
MYGROUP_6 = 'ff15:7079:7468:6f6e:6465:6d6f:6d63:6173'
```

to

```
MYGROUP6 = 'ff0n::nnn:nnnn:nnn:nnnn'
```

^ you will need to use netstat to find your IPv6 Multicast Group address(es):

```
$ netstat -gsv | grep ff0
```

Comment: fe80:: is the link-local interface not a multicast group.

Comment: @Steve-o - I must have needed some sleep, thanks for catching that.